# Перестала работать функция при переносе в новую тему на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. прошу помощи - не могу разобраться уже несколько дней. Опыта в WP немного, поэтому разобраться в текущем вопросе мне сложно.
Суть проблемы - Есть проект на WP + Yootheme Pro и в нем страница, с которой не могу разобраться.
Нужная страница выводит новости по пяти тематикам в пяти местах.
и еще есть фильтр из 10 тегов, который может фильтровать всю пачку новостей из базы данных сразу по нескольким тегам. Контент в админке есть.
мне нужно это воссоздать в новой теме и я решил просто пересоздать шаблон в новой теме без изменений кода со старой темы, где это все уже написано и работает.

```
the_post(); 

<div class="key-prod">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="title-h1 title-h1--white text-center">Key Products</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="key-prod__list row">

            <?php if(function_exists('have_rows')&& have_rows('vip-list')): ?>

                <?php while( have_rows('vip-list') ): the_row();?>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('vip-list__link');?>" title="<?php the_sub_field('vip-list__title');?>" class="key-prod__list-item">
                            <div class="key-prod__list-bg"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('vip-list__img');?>"></div>
                            <div class="key-prod__list-content">
                                <div class="title-h3"><?php the_sub_field('vip-list__title');?></div>
                                <div class="key-prod__list-text text-mini"><?php the_sub_field('vip-list__text');?></div>
                                <div class="key-prod__list-btn">
                                    <div class="btn-text">Learn more ></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

    </div>
</div><!--end key prod-->

<div class="solutions">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="solutions__nav">
                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'parent'                   => 0,
                        'hide_empty'               => 0,
                        'number'                   => '0',
                        'taxonomy'                 => 'solutions_tags',
                        'pad_counts'               => true );

                    $catlist = get_categories($args);
                    foreach ($catlist as $categories_item) {
                        echo "<span data-tag='tag-$categories_item->cat_ID' class='solutions__nav-link'>$categories_item->cat_name</span>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <!--<span class="solutions__nav-link solutions__nav-link--clear">Clear Filter</span>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div>

        <?php
        $posts_a = array();
        $terms = get_terms("solutions_cat");
        if (count($terms)) {
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $args = array(
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_type' => 'solutions',
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'solutions_cat' => $term->slug
                );
                $posts = get_posts($args);
                if ($posts) {
                    foreach ($posts as $post) {
                        $posts_a[$term->name][] = $post;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($posts_a):
            ?>
            <div class="solutions__prod-wrap">
                <? $c_cat = '';
                foreach ($posts_a as $cat => $posts):
                    ?>
                    <div class="solutions__prod">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="title-h2 text-center"><?= $cat ?></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="solutions__prod-list">
                                        <? foreach ($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="solutions__prod-list-item tag-tag-<?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'solutions_tags', array("fields" => "ids")); echo implode(' tag-tag-', $term_list);  ?>">
                                                <div class="solutions__prod-list-bg">
                                                    <span>
                                                        <?php
                                                        MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('solutions', 'solutions-mini', NULL,  'solutions-solutions-mini-thumbnail');
                                                        ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="solutions__prod-list-title"><?php the_title();?></div>
                                                <div class="solutions__prod-list-text">
                                                    <?php the_excerpt();?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="solutions__prod-list-btn">
                                                    <div class="btn-text">Learn more ></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        <? endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <? endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        <?endif;?>

        <div class="solutions__prod--col-wrap">
            <div class="solutions__prod solutions__prod--col">
                <div class="container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>

<?php if( trim(get_field('banner-solutions__title')) || trim(get_field('banner-solutions__text')) || trim(get_field('banner-solutions__link')) ):  ?>
    <div class="solutions-form">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <?php if( trim(get_field('banner-solutions__title')) ):  ?>
                        <div class="title-h1 title-h1--white"><?php the_field('banner-solutions__title');?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( trim(get_field('banner-solutions__text')) ):  ?>
                        <div class="text"><?php the_field('banner-solutions__text');?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( trim(get_field('banner-solutions__link')) ):  ?>
                        <div class="solutions-form__btn">
                            <a href="<?php the_field('banner-solutions__link');?>" class="btn-big btn-big--green">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

все это я переношу в шаблон новой темы. Но при переносе этот шаблон перестает выводить контент с первым блоком где условие have_rows('vip-list'). Мне кажется, нужно переопределять wp_query() так, как он определялся в старой функции в самом начале the_post(). Но не понимаю что там должно быть. Что можно сделать в ситуации? Я попробовал выводить таксономии - они выводятся, но в рамках переопределения wp_query ничего не находится в условии. И вторая сложность - не понимаю где в админке найти поля vip-list, по которым фильтруется первый вывод блока из трех карточек. Это кастомные поля, которые прикреплены к нужным постам, но самого обозначения vip-list в админке найти не могу. Где их найти?

```
        $taksonomii = get_taxonomies();

        foreach( $taksonomii as $taksonomiya ) {
            echo $taksonomiya . '<br />';
        }


        $categories = get_terms('solutions_cat', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0');


        if($categories){


        echo '<select>';

        foreach ($categories as $cat){

        echo "<option value='{$cat->term_id}'>{$cat->name}</option>";
        }
            echo '</select>';
        }

            // the query
            $args = array(
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'solutions_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array( 'web-tools' )
                    )
                )
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>


            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php
                    echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;
                 esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?
        print_r('до условия'); ?>
            <?php if(function_exists('have_rows')&& have_rows('vip-list')): ?>
        <? print_r('после условия'); ?>
                <?php while( have_rows('vip-list') ): the_row();?>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('vip-list__link');?>" title="<?php the_sub_field('vip-list__title');?>" class="key-prod__list-item">
                            <div class="key-prod__list-bg"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('vip-list__img');?>"></div>
                            <div class="key-prod__list-content">
                                <div class="title-h3"><?php the_sub_field('vip-list__title');?></div>
                                <div class="key-prod__list-text text-mini"><?php the_sub_field('vip-list__text');?></div>
                                <div class="key-prod__list-btn">
                                    <div class="btn-text">Learn more ></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow. Постарайтесь в будущем формулировать только одну проблему в вопросе.

Comment: В WordPress нет таких функции `have_rows()`, `the_row()` поэтому код падает на этой строчке. Вам придётся их копировать из старой темы.

Comment: Где ваши поля `vip_fileds` - сказать сложно. Я вижу обращение к `vip_list_title` через `the_sub_field()` - это не функция WordPress. Так что искать надо в старой теме. Скорее всего, `vip-list` записана в таблице `wp_options`, а `vip_list_title` - в `wp_post_meta`. Можно ли их увидеть в админке и где - вопрос к старой теме. Без ёё кода не ответить. Возможно, что-то увидите в админке поста, в Произвольных Полях.